# Regex for removing data in parenthesis

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to remove the parenthesis areas of these strings below, but I can't get a regex working :(

#### Data:

```
x (LOC)
ds ds (32C)
d'ds ds (LeC)
ds-d da(LOQ)
12345 (deC)
```

#### Regex tried:

```
[ \(\w+\)]
```

#### Regex101:

http://regex101.com/r/bD8fE2

#### Example code

```
items = ["x (LOC)", "ds ds (32C)", "d'ds ds (LeC)", "ds-d da(LOQ)", "12345 (deC)"]
for item in items:
    item = re.sub(r"[ \(\w+\)]", "", item)
    print item
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the square brackets; you are not matching a character class:

```
item = re.sub(r" \(\w+\)", "", item)
```

Demo:

```
>>> items = ["x (LOC)", "ds ds (32C)", "d'ds ds (LeC)", "ds-d da(LOQ)", "12345 (deC)"]
>>> for item in items:
...     print re.sub(r" \(\w+\)", "", item)
... 
x
ds ds
d'ds ds
ds-d da(LOQ)
12345
```

The one-but last example has no space preceding the opening parenthesis (`(`) and thus doesn't match. You could make the space optional if you need that pattern to work too:

```
item = re.sub(r" ?\(\w+\)", "", item)
```

Perhaps matching anything that isn't a closing parenthesis would work for you as well:

```
item = re.sub(r" ?\([^)]+\)", "", item)
```

This matches a wider range of characters than just `\w`.

In a regular expression, square brackets, `[...]`, denote a character class; a set of characters to match *once*. The class `[ \(w+\)]` means: match *one* character, if it matches the set including a space, an opening parenthesis, all characters of the `\w` class, a `+` plus, or a closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 5):

Anything within square brackets are taken irrespective of the order in which you have the characters because `[ ... ]` is a character class. remove them entirely:

```
r" \(\w+\)"
```

And I would add a `?` for an optional space:

```
r" ?\(\w+\)"
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/kZ3iY1)